# Managing user entitlements in Sails App

Tags: javascript, authentication, authorization, sails.js

I am building a web app based on Sails.JS. It has a user modle with authentication. I want to add a field of entitlements to users, which are securely managed (i.e. the user can't change the entitlements themselves), they can only be changed by achieving certain thigns in the app, or paying via Stripe API etc.

I thought that adding an array of entitlements in the user model and then adding to these when the neccessairy conditions are met within the app. Is that a good way to structure this functionality? I am just thinking that it might be a bit tricky to stop users changing these, but allowing them to change their email etc. ?

I would really appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to create a service to allow the user to update the fields you want them to update (something like a ProfileController which accepts only email/name), and not expose the `User` model blueprints directly. This would ensure that you can control the fields that a user can update through the REST APIs.

In a controller:

```
updateProfile: function(req, res) {

  var options = {
    name: req.param('name'),
    email: req.param('email')
  };

  // delegate off to a service to do the actual user updating
  UserService.updateProfile(req.token.id, options, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err.status, err.message);
    }

    return res.json(data);
  });
}
```

Then just call the `/updatProfile` end point from your application

Comment: and then how would I "securely" update the entitlements when the conditions had been met in the app logic?